I can't request IAPS (International Affective Picture System)
I'm going to run a survey experiment that induces some emotions,
To do so, I'd like to put IAPS pictures as manipulations of emotions. These images can induce emotions such as anger, disgust, etc, and appeared to have worked well across various regional contexts, and their robustness has been examined through many studies.
so I have Googled to request IAPS images, but their official website cannot be accessed,
plus, their email address (media@cseamedia.org) replied to me with an automatic response that notified "You failed to send a message."
Could anyone assist me in accessing/requesting IAPS images? Your help would be greatly appreciated in furthering my research.
Edit of April 11
For someone who has a similar question, I share a reply from
University of Florida:  the iaps images is currently not available from distribution ans is not clear whether that will be distributes in the future.

Hello, IAPS pictures are images to induce emotions such as anger, disgust, etc. They appeared to have worked well across various regional contexts and its robustness has been examined through many studies. So I haven't considered its alternatives yet.

I saw a post that had similar problems to mine. See this post But for some reason, scholars have used these images: example1, example2 So I'd like to know somebody who is faimilar with this problem.

Just in case, also see: Is there any good alternative to the International Affective Picture System (IAPS)?
